# Color string from object (random if empty, deterministic else)

Tags: python

```
from random import random

def to_color(obj=None):
    """Determine a color (string 000000-ffffff) from the hash of any object

    If no argument is passed, a random color is returned.

    Args:
        obj: any hashable object; string, tuple, ...

    Returns:
        a color string in range '000000' to 'ffffff'
    """
    obj = obj if obj else random()
    return "{0:06x}".format(abs(hash(obj)))
```

My questions:

1. Is the line `obj = obj if obj else random()` idiomatic?
2. Is `hash(obj)` the "proper" way to get a deterministic yet scrambled string for my purpose?
3. The `abs` takes care of negative hash values (e.g. from hashing negative integers). Is there a better way which doesn't collide so easily for small (absolute) integer values? (Right now, `to_color(500)` is equal to `to_color(-500)`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
>   is not, never the equality operators.
>
> Also, **beware of writing if x when you really mean if x is not None** --
>   e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None
>   was set to some other value. The other value might have a type (such
>   as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!

What you should do in your case is : `obj = obj if obj is not None else random()`.

Then, even though I like the ternary operator, I reckon its usage is not required/idiomatic here. The usual way to handle default parameter is more like

```
if arg is None:
    arg = default()
```

As far as I can tell, using `hash` like you did is ok. However, I guess you should handle values that could be out of the range you are expecting (I couldn't find easily something telling which range of values can be returned).